# How to use call-outs with imported image (Visio 2013)

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

How do I force a call-out to point to specific points on a photo imported into a Visio document?

When I try this, the arrow-head end of the call-out attaches itself to the edge of the photo -- not what I want. I am taking this approach to identify particular points in the photo of a vehicle so that I can edit the call-outs after saving the document. I could do the same with MS Paint but editing the text later is messy as I would have to blank-out the old text and add new text. Importing the photo into Visio works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Answered on the Visio Guy forum:

[How to use call-outs with imported image](http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=8597.msg37443;topicseen#msg37443)